# docker build goes into interactive mode in terminal?

Tags: docker

I did this

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 -v /Users/admin/Documents/docker-tut/frontend a69c09e48c75
```

and I got

[image]

emm why? it's not building but went into interactive mode.

Comment: probably because `a69c09e48c75`'s entrypoint is a shell

Comment: @tkausl that is my image's id

Comment: And whats your images entrypoint?

Comment: not sure isn't it within the app? here `/Users/admin/Documents/docker-tut/frontend`

Comment: This is working...

Comment: @DerekBrown then why I'm getting above problem?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much an error, as a misunderstanding of how Docker works.  Every container has a entrypoint, a single process which is run when the container is started, and when this process is terminated, the container stops.

The `-it` flag allocates a pseudo-tty and starts the docker container in interactive mode- meaning it allows you to interact with the endpoint process interactively (stdin, stdout, etc).  The output you are getting is actually this interface- the container is running, and allowing you to pass input into the entrypoint.

Based on your question, it seems like you want to daemonize your container (is run it in the background).  To do this, use the `-d` flag instead of `-it`.